# error: ‘struct sigevent’ has no member named ‘sigev_notify_thread_id’

Tags: c++, linux, timer, signals

The following "toy" code represents a problem I am having in a larger code base using [POSIX timers](http://linux.die.net/man/2/timer_create).

```
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    struct sigevent sevp;
    long threadId = 5;

    sevp.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD_ID;
    sevp.sigev_notify_thread_id = threadId;

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it using `g++` on a Linux machine I get the error:

```
error: ‘struct sigevent’ has no member named ‘sigev_notify_thread_id’
```

Is there a reason why? [This](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sigevent) leads me to believe that the `sigevent` struct has a member called `sigev_notify_thread_id`.

Comment: Thanks @Duck. `sevp._sigev_un._tid` and line 295 "here - http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h#L295" fixed my problem. Post that as an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `sevp.sigev_notify_thread_id` to `sevp._sigev_un._tid` fixed my problem. You can see the definition on line 295 [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h#L295).

Thanks to @Duck for the helpful comment.